# If a .gz file was downloaded can it demage my computer or steal data?

Tags: malware, gzip, malware-removal, malware-detection, gz

I was unaware that I was on a data phishing landing page (it was very clever, I haven't seen anything like this before) and I downloaded a .gz file. After that it started to become suspicius so I deleted the file and also get rid of it from the trash. I did not click on it and I did not unzipped it.

Considering this scenario, should I worry and make serious security steps and clean my computer or it can not harm my data (passwords) and my computer in any way?

Comment: If you never executed the file you downloaded then the file you downloaded posed little risk, I would be more worried, about payloads you unknowingly downloaded and were executed.

Comment: I do not think anyone can tell you all is well.  Do full online and offline scans with WD and make sure you have good encryption on passwords.

Comment: @John - “good encryption on passwords”, encrypting passwords is a horrible idea, passwords should be protected by hashing algorithms to avoid being able to reverse the encryption. Furthermore, outside the password to FDE encryption, how a password to a website or paid service is protected is entirely outside of the authors control. I don’t even know what you mean by that statement to be honest

Comment: I use KeePass:  ........     KeePass database files are encrypted. KeePass encrypts the whole database, i.e. not only your passwords, but also your user names, URLs ...

Comment: As others mentioned, unless the file was opened, there was no problem from *that*. But if you are still concerned, do an offline malware scan, e.g., see https://www.lifewire.com/free-bootable-antivirus-tools-2625785. Before using **any** downloaded file, check it at VirusTotal, https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload

Comment: Get  decent anti virus and makware detector programs